# how to find a word and copy the previous sentence from that word in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

i need to find a word in `<ad>` tag  the word is **movie** and get the previous sentence from the beginning of the tag

input example

```
<c>

 <ad>The hero movie 2014, is very good </ad>

    <b>nothing</b>

</c>
```

output needed

```
<a>

<first>The hero movie</first>

</b>

</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `substring-before()` function.